# How to specify default namespace for <xsl:element ...> productions?

Tags: firefox, xslt, xhtml

I have an XML with unnamed namespace, think like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="<see below>" ?>
<root>
    <child>Hello</child>
</root>
```

Which I intend to transform with XSLT to an X(HT)ML tree. Some of the things I would like to get away with are:

1. Do not use the "xsl:" prefix in the transformation stylesheet (below). This is for tersity, although I am keeping in mind that I may be paying for reduction in typing out my XSL code with extra verbosity in typing everything else. Anyhow, I would like to see how it pans out with just using unprefixed XSL syntax.
2. I am outputting HTML as an XHTML (and thus by extension, XML-compliant) tree. Not text and not "HTML text" -- the output method is "xml". This is to save the user agent from having to parse the [HTML] text.
3. I want to use XSL `element` elements to generate result tree. Not typing out the '<' followed by element name, followed by '>'.

Basically, I want to see how I can do a generic XML->XML transformation, where the resulting tree is an XHTML node or document, compatible with HTML 5.

The *unfinished* XSL stylesheet file in its simplified form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <output method="xml" />
    <template match="/">
        <element name="h1">
            <text>Hello World.</text>
        </element>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

I intend to have HTML's  `html` and `body` elements as ancestors of that `h1`, and actually transform source node(s). But the example should suffice to illustrate my impending problem -- I want the `h1` element in the resulting tree to belong to its rightful XHTML namespace. Without an explicit namespace declaration for the `element` node through the `namespace` attribute, it seems that the user agent interprets it as an unknown node with name `h1`. Fair enough, I guess.

What I don't want to do is have `namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` added to every instance of `element` XSL element, of which I may have dozens, obviously. Sadly, this currently looks like my only option. Provided that I use the XSL namespace as default for the stylesheet document, can I somehow imply that the resulting tree elements belong to XHTML namespace by default?

I understand that my perverted corner case may be why most folks use `xsl:` prefix explicitly, but I want to avoid it, given how the XSL is the namespace of the document after all. But if it is a limitation of XSLT 1.0, then I will concede.

The XML is transformed and rendered by Firefox 48.

Comment: What is the expected output of the transformation?

Comment: Like I said, an XHTML node tree. Which would consist of one or more XHTML elements.

Comment: I am afraid your assumption 'the output method is "xml". This is to save the user agent from having to parse the [HTML] text' is not really meaningful, in the browser world the Mozilla browsers like Firefox or Seamonkey do create a result tree and render it, whether you have output method `html` or `xml`, while other implementations feed the serialized result of the XSLT transformation on to the HTML or XML parser, whether you use output method `html` or `xml` does matter.  And as you want to be compatible with HTML5 I would suggest not to use namespaces and to use output method `html`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Well sure they create a result tree, in the case with "xml" output method I was arguing that that's what creates the tree, as actual DOM tree, without first generating text and then parsing it, as it happens when you load HTML text files over HTTP or disk. So the parsing stage is eliminated because Firefox produces the tree by applying XSLT and then renders it. Are you asserting that I am getting a text stream either way? It is certainly possible, but can you corroborate that claim? As for HTML 5 namespaces, well, I find XHTML superior to HTML 5 as far as parsing goes.

Comment: Firefox creates and renders the result tree of the XSLT transformation, whether you use output method `xml` or `html`. That is why it does not support `disable-output-escaping` at all nor Javascript `document.write` in the HTML result of an XSLT transformation (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ which says "Mozilla in contrast renders exactly the result of your transformation" and "Disabling output escaping requires us to add a parsing step to our output generation, which we don't.".

Comment: @MartinHonnen I think I should thank you for the clarification you provided, regardless, it's a very useful bit of information. The question is now somewhat irrelevant, and I no longer recall why I wanted XHTML specifically, as opposed to HTML, but this should definitely help people with a similar problem and opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most folks use the `xsl:` prefix because it's convenient to do so. Among other things, it allows you to define another namespace as the default namespace, thus avoid the need to explicitly add a namespace to every `element` instruction and to every literal result element.

In your example, you could simply bind another prefix to the XHTML namespace and use it instead of the full namespace:

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<template match="/">
    <element name="x:h1">
        <text>Hello World.</text>
    </element>
</template>

</stylesheet>
```

or (same thing):

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<template match="/">
    <x:h1>
        <text>Hello World.</text>
    </x:h1>
</template>

</stylesheet>
```

---

Note also that the default namespace is inherited. You could declare the the XHML namespace as the default at the root level of your output tree, and have all its descendants inherit it. The problem here is that your XSLT instructions would have to be excepted:

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <body>
            <text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">Hello World.</text>
        </body>
    </html>
</template>

</stylesheet>
```

Hopefully now you see why using a prefix such as `xsl:` is standard.

Comment: Thanks, that explains pretty much everything to me in this regard. It's good to know that what I wanted *is* possible, but short of specifying some default namespace for result tree, which may or may not be a good idea, these solution illustrates, like you said, why the `xsl:` prefix may be considered standard. I went with the prefix and not using `xsl:element` (well, for variable name elements I think one cannot avoid it).